# ld.exe cannot find "-ldl, -lm, -landroid, etc" on Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, sdk, android-ndk, toolchain

I've just installed Delphi 12 to work with Android applications. My SDK installed components are:

[image]

But, when I try compiling for any Android architecture, even with an empty multi-platform project, I receive the following errors:

```
Line 1: path\ld.exe: cannot find -ldl
Line 2: path\ld.exe: cannot find -lm
Line 3: path\ld.exe: cannot find -landroid
Line 4: path\ld.exe: cannot find -llog
Line 5: path\ld.exe: cannot find -ljnigraphics
Line 6: path\ld.exe: cannot find -lEGL
Line 7: path\ld.exe: cannot find -lGLESv2
Line 8: [DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

I already tried to reinstall Delphi and the SDK, but nothing worked.

How can I fix this error?